# Tensor Shape 'Reshape' during the dataflow

Tags: lstm, autoencoder, reshape

I would like to combine an Autoencoder with a LSTM. However, the 'timestep' is a block for the implements and I would like to train them together. Is there a solution to the tensor 'reshape'? I mean, it's not the simple 'Reshape' but for using timestep data.